# Potted indoor lemon tree

Tags: trees, lemons

For the last few months my lemon tree has been losing its leaves. I recently discovered a lot of citrus scale on the tree. I cleaned them all off. Im wondering if the leaf drop is due to the scale bugs or something else.  Here is a few pics of some of the leaves. Thanks. [image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaf burn has many different causes.  One of which is sometimes pests as they could infect the plant.

It looks like it might be one of the list below.

Environmental leaf burn
Too hot / too dry

Bacterial leaf burn 
Reaccuring every year

Nutrient burn/deficiency 
Too much/too little fertiliser 
usually iron or manganese